# How to use "@odata.id" in JSON body when using the HTTP action in Azure Logic Apps?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I'm using Azure Logic Apps to call out to the Microsoft Graph API using the `HTTP - HTTP` action. For this API I need to execute a POST request with the following body:

```
{
   "@odata.id": "<guid>"
}
```

When I try to save the Logic App, this error shows:

```
Failed to save logic app <redacted>. The template validation failed: 'The template action '<redacted>' at line '1' and column '144589' is not valid: "Unable to parse template language expression 'odata.id': expected token 'LeftParenthesis' and actual 'Dot'.".'.
```

How can I use this attribute in my JSON payload?

EDIT: as requested, a screenshot of the part of the Logic App that generates the error on Saving.
[image: dot in attribute triggers save error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you.

Comment: Could you share a bit of code of your logic app, specifically on the part that generates the error? This could help us determine what is wrong with the syntax.

Comment: @PieterVandenheede I added a screnshot of the action. When configured like this, I cannot save the Logic App because of the '.' in '@odata.id'

Comment: @YannickReekmans `@` is a protected keyword in the logic app workflow definition language schema. can you try this `@@odata.id` please ?

Comment: @Thomas If you convert your comment as an answer, I will accept it! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From this article:

[Logic Apps workflow definitions with the Workflow Definition Language schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-definition-language)

> If you have a literal string that starts with the @ character, prefix the @ character with another @ character as an escape character: @@

So in your case, this should work:

```
{
  "@@odata.id": "your value here"
}
```